# Sync Framework custom providers to communicate over WCF

Tags: .net, wcf, synchronization, provider, microsoft-sync-framework

I'm using Microsoft Sync framework 1.0 (without ADO.NET services)

I have created 2 custom providers: Xml provider and database provider.

The code of both providers can be seen at:

http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/204110/MyBaseSyncProvider.cs

http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/204110/MyDbSyncProvider.cs

http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/204110/MyXmlSyncProvider.cs

The next step that I want to accomplish, is to make synchronization over WCF.

As I understand there is ProviderProxy class that I may use, but unfortunately all examples that I have found on MSDN involve using Sync Services for ADO.NET. These examples  typically use DbSyncProvider.

My questions is: Is it possible to implement synhronization over WCF using my custom providers (without using Sync Services for ADO.NET)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, it is possible to use whatever communications mechanism you'd like as the underlying transport for a custom SyncProvider.

Last time I did this, I ended up having both providers on the client, because there was too much state management involved if the destination provider actually lived out of process.

This means that you simply need to write a destination provider that performs whatever WCF communication you would like as part of its implementation.

Comment: Any tips on where to start the implementation?
Thank You

Comment: I found the best source of information was the sample code in the SDK. Back when I implemented some custom providers (~ half a year ago), I found precious little in the way of documentation or how-to guides.

Comment: Old question and answer, I know, but [this MSDN article on syncing over WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee819079.aspx) was published only a few months afterwards.